# Is there a way to inline initialize exception's Data?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to throw exception with additional data without creating exception variable. Something like this:

```
throw new Exception() { Data.Add("foo", "bar") };
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Would this not mean `throw` throws the pointer to the new `Exception` object? Edit: silly me, thought I was looking at C++ questions for some reason, just ignore what I said.

Comment: Just curious why do you want to do this? new Exception() is going to create a new exception variable anyway..

Comment: @luketorjussen: It's going to create a new *object*, but not a new *variable* (at the C# level).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to do that with:

```
throw new Exception { Data = { { "foo", "bar" } } };
```

(Assuming you're using C# 3, which has collection initializers...)

Of course you can do this in conjunction with constructor arguments:

```
throw new ArgumentException("paramName") { Data = { { "foo", "bar" } } };
```

Comment: Wow, did't know I can use that on readonly properties. By the way, it should be `{{ "foo", "bar" }}` since it is dictionary

Comment: Wouldn't it be `Data = { { "foo", "bar" } }` because the `Data` property is an IDictionary? Doesn't each KeyValuePair need it's own set of curly braces, or is that unnecessary syntax?

Comment: @Poma: You can use it like that because it's an embedded object initializer; you're not actually setting `Data` to a new collection, you're just adding items to it. You can do the same to set properties on a value.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use object initializers to call methods like this.

Comment: You can if the method is called Add and the Data property type implements IEnumerable...

Answer (score 0):

It does have a `parametrized constructor` taking string;

```
  throw new Exception("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear (i.e. what is the Type of Data...)
If you mean that you need to put some message into Exception:

```
throw new Exception (Data.Add("foo", "bar").ToString());
```

Comment: thanks... didn't think of that. I see Jon Skeet thought of it, so just ignore my answer.